# Batch file to run an MS Access query and

Tags: database, ms-access, batch-file

I have an Access DB which has query to retrieve data from teradata. I want to create a batchfile which will execute that particular query.

Comment: teradata ? what did you try ?

Comment: i have a huge datasource in teradata.. my query executes fine... but i want it to be executed from a batch file so that the user need not open Access and run the query...

Answer (score 9):

You can create a macro to run the query and then exit Access, then use a command line switch to automatically run this from a batch file.

*Example:*

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office11\msaccess.exe" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office11\samples\northwind.mdb" /X mcrRunQueryAndQuit
```

More detail on Access command line switches: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209207

(Should work for Access 2000 - 2010)

Comment: thanks a lot Soupy.. it just worked fine.. all i need to do is schedule the task which i can do it from a scheduler... I tried to create a .vbs file which did not work with my .accdb Access database. Now with the above code i created a .bat and it worked perfect. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

VBA for Microsoft Access is your key.

Video tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9pqmd2PSYk